# Umbraco 7 - Extending RTE settings

Tags: plugins, umbraco, umbraco7, rte

My goal is to extend umbraco's Rich Text Editor data type to include a "char limit" field. Then, when using the data type in document type editor, there would be a field for a char limit to be set (rather than using a regex validation for that).

I have googled but the only thing I found until now was [how to extend the RTE to add more buttons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikerichter/2010/12/20/how-to-add-a-custom-button-and-plugin-to-tinymce-in-umbraco-4-5/).

Is this achievable?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite RTE's 'onKeyDown' event and handle the limit in the function's body. The url you provided in example shows how to create a field.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.on("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode); //Your logic goes here
});
```

The next steps depend on how you are going to create your char limit. The easier solution is to set up a validation onSave event, also you can parse keydown's event object and return false, if the limit is exceeded